# What happens when the opinion of the Court misrepresents the facts of the case?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, precedent

In *Kennedy v. Bremerton School District* (2022), the Court ruled 6–3 in favor of a high school football coach who had been leading players in prayer and was instructed by the school district to stop. [[PDF](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/21-418_i425.pdf)]

Justice Sotomayor's dissent disputes some of the characterizations in the majority opinion:

> To the degree the Court portrays petitioner Joseph Kennedy’s prayers as private and quiet, it misconstrues the facts.

For purposes of this question, let's assume that the above statement is correct that the majority opinion is wrong. What are the effects of substantive factual errors in an opinion? Like, for example:

- I assume that this specific ruling is not affected in any way by the text of the opinion? (Like, I assume that even an opinion of the form "We got high and decided to rule wrongly for fun" wouldn't actually negate the ruling?)
- How does this affect the precedent? Will courts in the future consider the true facts of the case (whatever they perceive them to be), or will they accept as legal fiction that the facts were as the Court describes them?
- Could it be legal for the district to repeat exactly the same set of actions in exactly the same set of true circumstances as before, since those *won't* be the same circumstances that the Court claimed to rule on?
- In this instance, the Court seems to be reversing the lower court's ruling directly; but sometimes the Court remands a case to a lower court in order to decide it on a different basis than it had. In such a case, is the lower court bound by the Supreme Court's characterization of the facts of the case, or can it use the true facts of the case as long as it obeys the ruling itself?

Comment: In reading the judgement they didn't really disagree about the *facts*, they just interpreted them differently e.g. the Coach said he wanted to pray silently and others joined him voluntarily (preumably because the school had tried to stop him). whereas the dissent portrays it as a pattern of conduct.

Comment: The statement of the incorrect facts would limit the scope of the precedent here -- if the court finds that the coach did pray silently and that was within bounds, this cannot be used as precedent that leading a prayer group is also within bounds.

Comment: I would urge a bit of caution. Her claim only means the facts are in dispute, not that her version is necessarily correct. In this case there's also room for real question about "how quiet is quiet?" and "how private is private?" I realize that doesn't change your basic question though.

Comment: So, the case apparently states *"The contested exercise here does not involve
leading prayers with the team; the District disciplined Mr. Kennedy
only for his decision to persist in praying quietly without his students
after three games in October 2015."* It seems the court decision doesn't even consider the events after that, where the coach continues the practice at away games, and where the coach became something of a "leader of prayer" as more and more people joined him.

Comment: After reading some of the decision, I'm wondering whether the case answers the two main questions of "physically separate" and whether students may be join. Before his dismissal, Kennedy was informed that he may continue to pray if "such activity must be physically separate from any student activity, and students may not be allowed to join such activity." Physically separate is touched, since "after the event" is the focus, but student involvement is a weird question though, since I'd expect that a student joining is exercising that same right that allows it in the first place.

Comment: For clarity, could you re-phrase at least most of that?

As it stands, the Question seems to be purely about opinion…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: If your comment amounts to "Your question is unclear, please rewrite it", then, could you provide some information about what's unclear to you? (Why do you think it's about opinion? . . . unless you mean "opinion" in the legal sense, in which case, why do you think that's a problem?)

Comment: Even before the bullet points, “… a football coach had been leading players in prayer and was instructed…  to stop” is hardly a clear summary of a 75-page ruling… and itself misconstrues the facts. One group of judges must be wrong but on the question of the prayers being private or quiet, the Sotomayor dissent seems to describe a different case altogether. Still, it’s not obvious how any of those bullets needs KvBSD at all, as shown in ohwilleke's Answer. So yes, it’s highly unclear.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Oh, I see — you're not saying you don't understand the question, you're just using "unclear" to mean "I don't like it", and "highly unclear" to mean "I really don't like it". Unfortunately, I don't think it's feasible for me to rewrite the question every time someone comes by who dislikes it; so, respectfully, I think I'll leave it as is.

Comment: It's not clear here whether you're just being offensive, or trying to be deliberately obtuse; either way, please don't. Like it or not your Question was unclear, for reasons including those I gave. Without argument, ohwilleke's Answer clearly shows that none of those bullets needs KvBSD at all. Reading even much, let alone all of that 75-page Opinion shows its you and Sotomayor who misconstrue. Please try harder.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: So, I'm pretty sure your complaint is motivated by politics, and your claim that the question seems "unclear" to you is just pretense; but on the off-chance that you've sincerely misunderstood that word, please see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unclear .

Comment: @ruakh What happens if a Court misrepresents the facts matters, and trudging through the 75 pages you offered makes it clear both that KvBSD throws little light on the Question and that your analysis misconstrues the case. 

I don't want to break forum rules by arguing in Comments but should that excuse your belligerence or licence you to Post nonsense, let alone both?

Could you be less offensive, or start addressing the issues?

If the Question benefitted by citing KvBSD why not say how?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @ruakh On the other hand, why not you agree that what you first Posted was for several reasons, at best unclear and what you followed up with was mostly just offensive; almost certainly, deliberately and gratuitously offensive? Would you like agree to that, or ask other Members to put it to a vote in Chat?

You're entitled to continue venting your views here and if you do, please address the issues.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What are the legal consequences of substantive factual errors in an
> opinion?

None.

> I assume that this specific ruling is not affected in any way by the
> text of the opinion?

Correct.

> I assume that even an opinion of the form "We got high and decided to
> rule wrongly for fun" wouldn't actually negate the ruling?

Probably not, but it might precipitate a constitutional crisis or lead to an impeachment.

> How does this affect the precedent?

It doesn't.

> Will courts in the future consider the true facts of the case
> (whatever they perceive them to be),

No.

> will they accept as legal fiction that the facts were as the Court
> describes them?

Yes.

> Could it be legal for the district to repeat exactly the same set of
> actions in exactly the same set of true circumstances as before, since
> those won't be the same circumstances that the Court claimed to rule
> on?
>
> In such a case, is the lower court bound by the Supreme Court's
> characterization of the facts of the case,

Generally speaking the lower courts are bound by characterizations of the facts made by the appellate court. But, it depends to some extent on the procedural posture of the case.

In most cases, the findings of fact made by the trial court following an evidentiary hearing are binding on appellate courts in the U.S. unless they are not supported by any admissible evidence presented at trial, but there are some exceptions to this rule and there is considerable art as well as science that goes into properly characterizing the evidence presented at trial.

But, for example, many appellate cases are appeals from a dismissal of a case on a motion to dismiss at the outset of a case, in which all allegations of the Plaintiff's complaint in a civil matter are taken as true for sake of argument, and the legal issue presented is whether the Plaintiff can prevail if all of those facts are true.

In a case in that procedural posture, assuming that the appellate court reversed the trial court and found that the facts alleged state a claim upon which relief can be granted, then the remand would be to move forward with discovery and other pre-trial procedures in the case and ultimately a trial, if necessary, to determine the actual facts of the case as opposed to the facts as alleged by the Plaintiff in the complaint or petition.

Not infrequently, when appellate courts are divided over what happened in the trial court, one side of the debate, looking at the raw testimony and exhibits presented at trial, will conclude that the admissible evidence presented at trial did not support the findings of fact in a mixed question of fact and law made by a trial court judge, while another side of the debate will accept the trial court judge's findings of fact uncritically. It often isn't easy to know, from reading an appellate court opinion alone, which side is which in this regard.

> can it use the true facts of the case as long as it obeys the ruling
> itself?

Usually not. Usually, facts relied upon by an appellate court are by definition the correct facts (apart from clerical errors - e.g., an appellate court once misspelled my name in a court opinion, and the lower court wasn't bound by that mistake). This said, as noted above, the precise procedural posture of the case, nature of the court's opinion, and scope of the remand order is highly relevant to what a court can do on remand.

Comment: Any reason you apparently skipped over the question "Could it be legal for the district to repeat...?" It seems you suggest an answer of yes, since when trying a new case, a court would use the Supreme Court ruling as precedent only for the facts the Supreme Court stated?

Comment: @nanoman I left that out because it was unclear what was meant to the point of being nonsensical.

Comment: @ohwilleke: I didn't find it nonsensical.  Let's consider a really small example in the realm of book censorship.  School accepts a donation of books on topic X.  Court eventually rules that the school cannot spend taxpayer funds on topic X.  Can the school accept another donation of books, purchased with private funds, falling within the same topic?  I would think the answer is "yes, but they must make sure the donor covers all costs, including labeling, updating catalogs, and placing the books on the shelves" because that doesn't violate the court's order not to spend taxpayer funds.

Comment: @BenVoigt I wasn't able to discern such a clear meaning from the statement.

Comment: I find Ben Voight's point quite clear. Suppose a police officer punches a suspect in the nose, and says "I want you to confess". The suspect then confesses. Their lawyer files a motion to suppress the confession. It goes up to the Supreme Court as Smith v Jones. The Supreme Court then issues a ruling saying "The police officer in this case gave an ice cream cone to the suspect, then asked for a confession. We find that giving an ice cream cone to a suspect before asking for a confession does not constitute undue pressure. Therefore, the motion to suppress is denied."

Comment: Now there's another case where another police office punches another suspect in the nose, and then asks for a confession, and there's another motion to dismiss. The prosecutor says "In Smith v Jones, the Supreme Court found that punching a suspect in the nose does not constitute undue pressure. You should follow the precedent and deny the motion."

Comment: The defense attorney says "In Smith v Jones, the Supreme Court found that giving a suspect an ice cream cone does not constitute undue pressure. That was the pattern of facts on which they asserted that they based their ruling. Whether that is what happened in actuality is irrelevant to the precedent; the precedent only speaks to the proper ruling with respect to the asserted pattern of facts." 
Who's right? Does the precedent apply to the "actual" pattern of facts, or the asserted pattern of facts?

Comment: So could, in theory, with suitable conspiracy, this be exploited/abused to twist and direct precedent toward a particular agenda-driven and "in reality" fact-free direction?

Comment: @Acccumulation That sounds like a pretty well formed question. Maybe post it as a question? I would love to hear and answer I think the defense would be right but it would be interesting to hear an answer from someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: If the opinion misrepresents a fact, does that mean it becomes a precedent for the actual situation or a the misrepresented situation? That is, if an opinion states that a pet was a dog, and it was really a cat, would it be a precedent regulating dogs or cats?

Comment: @Acccumulation As a layman I took away a similar understanding from the OP. However I can't see that question arising unless the 2nd court reweighs of the evidence from *Smith v. Jones*. Isn't relitigating the facts an inappropriate use of prior case law? I'd think the 2nd count would have to consider the precedent based on erroneous facts stated in the opinion (ice cream cone). How could they do otherwise?

Comment: Otherwise they'd have to opine, "*Smith* established ice cream cones aren't undue pressure, but upon investigation we found that *gave an ice cream cone* is code for *punched in the face* so we will interpret the *Smith* opinion thus." How on earth could they make that assessment autonomously every time the facts are in dispute in a preceding case? Don't they have to trust the prior court's opinion? Maybe I'm a naive layman, idk....

Comment: @o.m.: I think dogs, and I think that's what ohwilleke means by answering "no" to "will courts in the future consider the true facts of the case". What "precedent" means, roughly speaking is, "if the established facts of your case match the established facts of the precedent case, then the same legal conclusion follows". Whether the established facts of the precedent case ever physically happened is neither here nor there. For that matter the established facts of your case might not have really happened.

Comment: @Accumulation: "In Smith v Jones, the Supreme Court found that punching a suspect in the nose does not constitute undue pressure". I don't think it did find that. In Smith v Jones the Supreme Court either found that the officer didn't punch the suspect, or at least didn't find that the officer did punch the suspect. So it made no ruling either way about whether or not punching a suspect is undue pressure. Neither did it rule whether holding the door open for the suspect on the way in is undue pressure (let's say the officer did that, but SCOTUS doesn't know or care because wasn't in evidence).

Comment: @The_Sympathizer: I reckon so: with a suitable conspiracy SCOTUS could issue precedents for circumstances that were never actually brought to it. Then again, with a suitable conspiracy, SCOTUS or other courts can ignore precedents anyway. Or find ways to rule that they aren't applicable after all. Plessey v Ferguson and Roe v Wade were both precedents until they weren't.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive: "is code for" - well, in applying a precedent the court has to decide what the original words of the precedent actually mean. Counter-factually, supposing "give an ice-cream cone" were slang for "punch in the face", or at least we could somehow persuade our judge that it is, then of course this puzzling SCOTUS characterisation of the case becomes entirely clear, and we realise that indeed it did rule that punching someone in the face is not undue pressure. That's not law, though, that's just post-modernism ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Appellate courts are not finders of fact.  Appeals courts are supposed to resolve questions of **law**.  The job of a court of appeals isn’t supposed to be to second-guess whether the witnesses are telling the truth.  Sometimes, as you mention, an appellate judge does point out that the factual record they’re presented with does not make sense, but, in theory, that isn’t what they’re reviewing.

The facts of the case are relevant to that one case.  What the Supreme Court actually decided was not whether that one person had prayed too loudly or not, but that “The Free Exercise and Free Speech Clauses of the First Amendment protect an individual engaging in a personal religious observance from government reprisal.”   That holding doesn’t depend in any way on the actual volume of that one plaintiff’s prayers.  (All right, sometimes it can, because someone says, “If even that was legal, this has to be,” but if someone were worried about that, she would have been motivated to emphasize how very very exceptionally quiet this one prayer that’s allowable really was.) Similarly, the landmark case of *Lawrence v. Texas* was widely misreported in 1993 as beginning with a SWATTing of two gay men by a homophobic neighbor, when in fact it was a jealous boyfriend (although I see the opinion itself stuck to the passive voice and thus did not end up repeating it).  This didn’t matter to the conclusion that sodomy laws against consenting adults in private violate the Constitution.

This is where the maxim, “Tough cases make bad law,” come from.  Lawyers love to hand-pick the most sympathetic petitioners or the most unsympathetic defendants imaginable, so that it will feel like a miscarriage of justice if their side doesn’t win this specific case.  But courts of appeals are actually establishing rules for how other cases must be decided in the future.  The reasoning they come up with to justify one verdict in an unusual case often turns out to be a bad precedent for other cases.

The Supreme Court isn’t a trial court where people present new evidence.  More precisely, the side that lost makes a list of all the errors they claim the judge made that they wnt to be overruled, and the higher court decides whether it will hear the arguments for and against.  This is why the Supreme Court only has thirty-minute question periods: both parties to the case already submitted their written briefs where they lay out the case, and now the justices will ask any further questions that they feel were not sufficiently addressed.  At this argument, the lawyers never say, “I have new evidence to introduce!” or “I want to call a witness!”  It’s not a trial where they do that.

The higher court might rule that the trial judge erred by not allowing one side to present evidence, or it might rule that the trial judge erred by allowing a jury to hear something it should not have.  If that happens, it orders there to be a new trial, with a new jury, that gets to hear the new evidence and decide based on that.

There’s no other court to appeal to from a decision by the Supreme Court.  (Hence the famous quip, “We’re not last because we’re right; we’re right because we’re last.”)  @DavePhD informed me that it can be petitioned to rehear a case it just decided, with a 25-day time limit.

However, it has happened that a case raised an issue of law that made the Supreme Court order a retrial, and in the new trial, a different question of law came up that also was appealed to the Supreme Court, so it heard the same case a second time.  *Powell v. Alabama*, the trial of the Scottsboro Nine, was one such case, establishing two different precedents (on the right to effective assistance of counsel and the unconstitutionality of calling in only White people for jury duty).  With the judge in one of these retrials throwing out the jury’s guilty verdict and declaring a mistrial because he was so sure their conviction had been wrongful, some of the nine defendants were tried four times. (On the same evidence, four of them ended up being acquitted, four were convicted, and one died in police custody.)

But, once a trial is over and its appeals are exhausted, the case is done.  It cannot be tried again.  This is called [res judicata](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/res_judicata), a thing that has been judged.  Norma McCorvey, better known as the pseudonymous “Jane Roe” in *Roe v. Wade*, even sued years afterward to have her own case overturned.  (Too soon?)  Notably, the **holdings** of that case were later overruled—in a separate case that raised the same issues and led the justices on today’s Supreme Court to reconsider them.  But the original case was not, and could not be, brought a second time to undo it, and someone tried.  Similarly, in another example I gave above, the court in *Lawrence v. Texas* reversed the conclusion it had reached in *Bowers v. Hardwick*, but without changing the outcome of the previous case (where the prosecutor ended up dropping the sodomy charge anyway).

Comment: Your final paragraph (and especially the last sentence) is unclear and reads like an attempt to slip in an opinion concerning a very recent decision that's a political hot potato, rather than choosing what would best illustrate your point.

Comment: @BenVoigt It wasn’t intended that way, but that might have been the reason it jumped immediately to my mind as an example of an attempt to re-try the exact same case. i’ll revise to clarify.

Comment: The sentence is still ambiguous, "paid off to do *it*" could be referring to appearing as lead plaintiff in the original case or to the later request to overturn the original.  Or maybe both.  I think you're better off just removing that claim, lest it devolve into an argument over whether being reimbursed for expenses is a payoff.

Comment: @BenVoigt i mean, i could quote her exact words, which were, “I took their money and they took me out in front of the cameras and told me what to say. That’s what I’d say,” You have persuaded me, though, that that line will distract readers from my main point.

Comment: Yeah, from that quote I still can't tell whether she's talking about the events before the 1973 ruling or in the attempt to overturn it.

Comment: @BenVoigt She was referring to the attempt to overturn it. I’ve simply removed all references to her motives in either case. The point of that example is, she was not allowed to bring the same case again once it was over and ask for a different verdict. The Court could, however, later reconsider whether its reasoning in the earlier case had been correct. In a new case that raised the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

US Supreme Court [rule 44](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/supct/rule_44) provides for rehearing of cases.

If, for example, there is an error, a party may request rehearing of the case and if a justice who agreed with the original decision thinks rehearing is appropriate, and a majority of the court agrees, the case will be reheard.

For more information see [When U.S. Supreme Court Decisions Are Not
Final: An Examination of the Rehearing Rule and
the Court’s Application of It in Kennedy v.
Louisiana](https://scholarship.shu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1035&context=student_scholarship#:%7E:text=Court%20can%20rehear%20cases%20on,days%20of%20the%20Court%27s%20decision.&text=original%20decision%2C%20must%20vote%20to%20rehear.&text=31%20Id.) (2010).

In [Kennedy v Louisiana](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/554/407/) a 5-4 major held that it was cruel and unusual to apply the death penalty to a man who raped and sodomized an 8 year old girl and ripped her body from vagina to anus.  The decision incorrectly stated that there was no federal legislation to apply the death penalty for rape.  After the decision, it was reported in the news media that actually there was a US military law allowing the death penalty for rape of a child.

Rehearing was requested, but only justices Thomas and Alito would [agree to rehear the case](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/07pdf/07-343Kennedy.pdf).

[Ambler v. Whipple](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/us/59145ee0add7b04934210b18) is cited in the above article as another example of a decision having a factual error.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I feel like the direct answer to the question is only implied, where it may be worth stating ~"In the case of incorrect facts the court may be petitioned to rehear the case." (I'm also suggesting an edit for more info on the Ambler v. Whipple case)

Comment: This answer is somewhat vulnerable to link rot. I think some key information from the linked resources (all publicly available) could've been quoted in the answer body. Right now, without the ability to click on any link, I just know there's some rule allowing rehearing and it's been used before, but nothing else.

Comment: @Mindwin and TCooper, I added more

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I think it is relevant information that Rule 44 has a 25-day time limit.

Answer (score 3):

I generally agree with [this answer by ohwilleke](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/81522/17500).  An error, even an egregious error, in the selection or, characterization of the facts in a case by the US Supreme Court has no direct legal consequences. Such an error offers no path to overturning the decision, except through a motion for a rehearing, which I understand rarely succeeds.

A dissent may point out such an error. While the decision is being considered by the court, that may or may not affect the views of other justices. Later, it may make the decision less likely to be followed and become an important precedent. It may lead to the decision being distinguished or simply ignored in later Supreme Court decisions. But there is no guarantee of either effect.

One case where the Court pretty clearly got the facts wrong was [*Buck v. Bell*, 274 U.S. 200 (1927)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_v._Bell) In that case, as the Wikipedia article puts it:

> the Court ruled that a state statute permitting compulsory sterilization of the unfit, including the intellectually disabled, "for the protection and health of the state" did not violate the Due Process Clause of the Fourteenth Amendment to the United States Constitution. Despite the changing attitudes in the coming decades regarding sterilization, the Supreme Court has never expressly overturned Buck v. Bell.

Justice Oliver Wendel Holmes famously declared in [the opinion](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/274/200) "Three generations of imbeciles are enough", referring to Carrie Buck, her mother, and her daughter. But it now seems clear that none of these individuals was in fact an "imbecile" (then a defined medical term), and the evidence purporting to show that they were was laughable even at the time. See "Carrie Buck's Daughter" an essay by Stephan Jay Gould.)

(The Court also failed to note that Carrie Buck's lawyer was affiliated with the other party, and may have intentionally presented a weaker case than he could have done.)

This err, error in finding the facts has not lead to any "legal consequences" in over 90 years, although other developments may have weakened the force of the case as a precedent.

When a Supreme Court decision (say *A v B*) says that:

> The facts in this case show that X was true, and therefore legal doctrine Q applies.

judges in future cases in lower courts may look to see if X is true before applying Q, whether X was actually true in the original case or not.  To that extent the incorrect facts stated in the Supreme Court opinion may form a rule of law.

Suppose that in the case the actual facts were Y, while the Court stated that they were X. If in a later case the facts are again Y, it might be argued that:

> The rule in *A v B* is that when X is true, Q applies. But here Y is true, not X, so that case is not relevant.

Sometimes when legal scholars, particularly in law review articles, point out what seems to be an error in legal reasoning, or an error in stating the facts, in a current decision, Justices become uneasy, and more willing to go a different way in similar later cases. But not always, and Justice Alito, in particular, has shown little attention to such criticism of his views or opinions.

Comment: +1. This is the only answer which addresses the important point that misrepresenting the facts changed the presidential value of the case, either strengthening it or (in this case) weakening it.

Comment: So Sotomayor simply disagrees? Fact X should not make legal doctrine Q? Where fact X is whatever was presented before the court?

Comment: @608 In the case mentioned I think that Sotomayor  disagrees with how the courtr interpreted the evidence from the trial court. But It is also possible for justices to disagree on the proper legal consequence of agreed facts.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be based on the premise that courts' decisions are meant to make sense at all times: if a decision isn't coherent, the court gets ashamed about it and corrects it promptly, or, at least, eventually gets forced to correct it (or a higher court, if there is one, does so).

First of all, the decision in question is delivered by the highest court of the country. The legal status of such decisions is always "in force" unless they get overturned by the court itself, or the legislators pass a law that  takes the decisions down. The reasoning which the court used to arrive to the decision (including any [mis]representations of facts) does not matter: the reasoning is given merely as *court*esy (pun intended) for those who would need to apply it as case law. Even if the reasoning included pure math errors — rendering the decision *objectively* wrong, it would still be in force until taken down the usual way.

If the court wasn't the highest one, there could be appellate remedies. Otherwise no difference.

Comment: Thanks! Just FYI, your first paragraph is mistaken about the premise of the question. (I'm not sure if there's something confusing about how I wrote it, or what. It doesn't seem to just be you; Mark Rosenblitt-Janssen's answer shows a similar misunderstanding.)

Comment: @ruakh I've changed the wording slightly. When someone assumes that there could be _any_ "legal consequences of substantive factual errors" in the top courts' decisions, I think it is reasonable to infer that the person perhaps thinks in the terms expressed in the 1st paragraph. Even though it is not the case in your case, the misconception is common.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I see how the phrase "legal consequences" could be misleading here, seeing as it usually has a different meaning. (I mean, I do feel that y'all could have just read the list of examples to see that that wasn't what I meant. But at least I understand now where the confusion came from.) I'll edit; thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In my estimation, there can be no legal ramification.  The Court does not answer to the People, like the Executive, but to the ideals and underpinnings of the Law.

However, one can resort to the Press to put pressure on the Court to revise their opinion or ruling, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! But I don't think this answer is really related to my question, which is about the legal status of mistaken factual claims in a majority opinion.